# NullReferenceException when adding InMemoryRandomAccessStream to list

Tags: c#, windows, list, uwp, stream

```
        private List<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> undoStreamList;            
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream tempStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(tempStream);
        undoStreamList.Add(tempStream);
        state++;
```

This code returns a `NullReferenceException` on the penultimate line, how do I fix it?

I also tried changing the penultimate line to `undoStreamList.Add(new InMemoryRandomAccessStream);` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your list has not been initialized:

```
// Initialize this either inline or inside the constructor...
private List<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> undoStreamList = new List<InMemoryRandomAccessStream>();

InMemoryRandomAccessStream tempStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(tempStream);
undoStreamList.Add(tempStream);
state++;
```

This is the only possible reason for that line throwing an exception!